# How to prove this Pythagorean Triple?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, elementary-number-theory

How do I prove that $(2mn, m^2 - n^2, m^2 + n^2)$ is true for $m>n>0$?

Since $m^2 + n^2$ is the hypotenuse, I applied the Pythagoren theorem:
$(2mn)^2 + (m^2 - n^2)^2 = (m^2 +n^2)^2$ and simplified it so that I would get $(m^2 + n^2)^2 = (m^2 + n^2)^2$ but I wasn't able to prove anything. How do I continue from here?

Thanks!

Comment: $(m^2+n^2)^2=(2mn)^2+(m^2-n^2)^2$

Comment: In short: you've neglected $m^2-n^2$ in squaring.

Comment: @J.M. Oh, sorry for the typographical error. So how do I show that it is true for $m>n>0$?

Comment: Just expand out all the squares and see if everything's right in both sides of your equal sign...

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Solutions_of_Pythagorean_Equation

Comment: @Juan, I've edited your answer at two places, so that you can see where the exponent 2 was missing. If you have a look now, you'll see that you in fact already proved it.

Comment: Oh so that's why I couldn't solve it. Thank you for pointing out my mistake!

Comment: @JuandelaJohn You could consider writing your calculation as an answer and accepting that. If the other users who helped you with their hints don't want to expand the hints to a full answer, it is very much ok for you to do so yourself. That way the community can check out and give you feedback on the presence of any lingering unclear steps (if any) in your argument. You also get piece of mind (and some rep). Also the automated system is relieved of the duty to periodically 'bump' your question to the front page as 'unanswered'. That kind of bumping reduces our enjoyment of the site :-)

Comment: Thank you for the tips on using this site @JyrkiLahtonen! I will post my answer.

Comment: Turns out that I'm not yet allowed to self-answer. I need to wait for 2 more hours

Comment: @JuandelaJohn Ok. let's wait! :-) Didn't mean to sound patronising. I just didn't know, whether you're aware of this practice.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen No problem! I wasn't aware of this practice and you were kind enough to point it out so thanks a lot! :)

Comment: The question was phrased as "How do I prove that $(2mn, m^2 - n^2, m^2 + n^2)$ is true?", but apparently meant "How do I prove that $(2mn, m^2 - n^2, m^2 + n^2)$ is a Pythagorean triple?".  Writing it like that would be clearer.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHardy, I'll make clearer questions next time

Comment: For the record: I very much prefer that people I managed to prod into coming up with the answer(s) on their own write up what they did as an answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

Realizing that I made a silly mistake, I reevaluated the equation and:

Given the Pythagorean Triple $(2mn, m^2-n^2,m^2+n^2)$ and $m>n>0$, we can apply the Pythagorean theorem to see if they are equal:

$(2mn)^2+(m^2-n^2)^2 = (m^2+n^2)^2$

$4m^2n^2 + (m^4-2m^2n^2+n^4) = (m^2+n^2)^2$

$m^4+2m^2n^2+n^4=(m^2+n^2)^2$

$(m^2+n^2)^2 = (m^2 + n^2)^2$

Answer (score 4):

**HINT** $\ $ By difference of squares $\rm \ (m^2+n^2)^2 - (m^2-n^2)^2 =\ (2\:m^2)\ (2\:n^2)\: =\: (2\:m\:n)^2 $

Comment: That was cool. Thanks!